# What does ||= do in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been using Ruby for a while now, and I keep seeing this:

```
foo ||= bar
```

What is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will assign `bar` to `foo` if (and only if) `foo` is `nil` or `false`.

EDIT: or false, thanks @mopoke.

Answer (score 7):

Operator ||= is a shorthand form of the expression:

x = x || "default"

Operator ||= can be shorthand for code like:

x = "(some fallback value)" if x.nil?

From: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators

Answer (score 2):

Assign `bar` to `foo` unless `foo` is a true value (not `false` or `nil`).

Comment: Should be: unless `foo` is truthy, where truthy means: not `false` or `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it for an instance variable, you may want to avoid it. That's because

```
@foo ||= bar
```

Can raise a warning if `@foo` was previously uninitialized. You may want to use

```
@foo = bar unless defined?(@foo)
```

or

```
@foo = bar unless (defined?(@foo) and @foo)
```

depending on whether you want to merely check if @foo is initialized, or check if @foo has truthiness (ie isn't `nil` or `false`).